# JavaScript Filter Method - Return only first object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, methods, refactoring

Using the filter() method in JavaScript, is it possible to return only the first instance that passes the test? Once I find first object in my cars array, I'd like to move this object from its current position to the beginning of the cars array.

**Code:**

```
     cars.filter(function(car) {

        var fareType = car.data("fareType");
        var partnerCode = car.data("partnerCode");

        if (fareType == "DEAL" && partnerCode == "AV")
        {
            // get first instance only and move element to beginning of array
        }

        if (fareType == "DEAL" && partnerCode == "BU")
        {
            // also get first instance where partnerCode == BU only and move element to beginning of array 
           // If dataPrice is less than dataPrice for partner AV, move to first position, else move to second position
        }
    });
```

Comment: @OriDrori `findIndex` is better, since he needs the index, not just the value.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
let index = cars.findIndex(function(car) {
    var fareType = car.data("fareType");
    var partnerCode = car.data("partnerCode");
    return (fareType == "DEAL" && partnerCode == "AV");
});
if (index !== -1) {
    let car = cars[index];
    cars.splice(index, 1);
    cars.unshift(car);
    /*
     * this could be reduced to:
     *
     *     cars.unshift(...cars.splice(index, 1));
     *
     * at the sake of clarity
     */
}

index = cars.findIndex(function(car) {
    return fareType == "DEAL" && partnerCode == "BU";
});
if (index !== -1) {
    let car = cars[index];
    cars.splice(index, 1);
    if (car.data('price') < cars[0].data('price')) {
        cars.unshift(car);
    } else {
        cars.splice(1, 0, car);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dave! I just updated my question with a follow-up. After I get the firstPosition of AV Deal, I also need to look for element where partnerCode == BU. Depending on which price is cheaper (AV vs. BU), I'll either have to move it to first or second position (before AV or vice versa). Can I achieve this using findIndex? Will I have to use more than one findIndex in this case?

Comment: you could just run essentially the same code again, but with a check to see where to insert it.  see edit

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex()`

```
var selectedIndex = cars.findIndex(function(car) {
    return car.data("fareType")== "DEAL" && car.data("partnerCode")== "AV";
});

if (selectedIndex > -1) {
   cars = [cars[selectedIndex], ...cars.slice(0, selectedIndex), ...cars.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
}
```

Comment: In case it matters, this creates a new array rather than modifying the original `cars` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
let indexToGoFirst = 0;

cars.some((car, index) => {
  const fareType = car.data('fareType');
  const partnerCode = car.data('partnerCode');

  if (fareType == 'DEAL' && partnerCode == 'AV') {
    indexToGoFirst = index;
    return True
  }
})

cars[0] = cars[indexToGoFirst];
```

The `.some()` checks if anything in the array matches the condition, and will stop looping when the condition is met, so you can use that to set the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Find index and create new array with element first

```
var index = cars.findIndex(function(car) {
        var fareType = car.data("fareType");
        var partnerCode = car.data("partnerCode");

        // get first instance only and move element to beginning of array

        return fareType == "DEAL" && partnerCode == "AV";

    });

var newCars = index > 0? [cars[index]].concat(cars.slice(0, index)).concat(cars.slice(index + 1): cars;
```